# Magento2: Add new Address fail

Tags: magento2, error, customer-address

i'm trying to add a new customer address using Magento 2 but after fill the form and submit not save nothing.

I have seen that 2 requests throw 302

```
Request URL:http://localhost/magento/customer/address/formPost/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:[::1]:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

and

```
Request URL:http://localhost/magento/customer/address/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:[::1]:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

any idea?

Comment: Should not use `localhost` as the top level domain. Try to use other domains. for example: `yoursite.loc`, `mage.local`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I installed magento2 using bitnami friends apps and now it works very fine!!

https://bitnami.com/stack/xampp